# grunt-contrib-connect - Fatal error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND my.website - How to set up custom URL?

Tags: javascript, url, gruntjs, localhost, grunt-contrib-connect

I want to use `grunt-contrib-connect` to create a server under a specific URL, let's say `http://my.website/`. According to the documentation, all I need to do is just to change the `hostname` option, but I keep getting an error saying: `Fatal error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND my.website`.

Here's my `Gruntfile.js`:

```
connect: {

    dev: {

        options: {

            keepalive:  true,
            port:       80,
            hostname:   'my.website',
            base:       'public'

        }

    }

},
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you edited your /etc/hosts file?

Comment: No - I thought I don't have to do it with a Grunt plugin. I thought that's one of the benefits of running a web server with Node.js vs something like MAMP. What IP do I add there? Just `my.website 127.0.0.1`?

Comment: Okay, adding `127.0.0.1` to the hosts file works fine. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, @firstdoit it does work only partially - while adding that entry to `hosts` made the desired URL available in the browse, I can't seem to listen on port `80`, Grunt keeps spitting out `Fatal error: listen EACCES'. I have no other web servers running. Any ideas?

Comment: Permission error - non-sudo users are not allowed to bind to ports lower than 1024. Two solutions: `sudo` or follow this gist: https://gist.github.com/firstdoit/6389682

Comment: I have added a complete answer for completeness sake. I find it important that problems are not only solved, but their roots are understood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hosts are merely "aliases" that other computers in the network (or your own!) can use to find IPs. Your machine may even control more than one IP (by having many network interfaces). However, **you can only listen to requests in IPs you control**!

When you start a server, it binds itself to a specific network interface (which has a specific IP address), in a specific port, and starts listening.

In your case the server failed to resolve `my.website` (because it really doesn't exist) and refused to listen on this address. It isn't one of your IPs!

**TL;DR:** You must add your desired host to `/etc/hosts` (Mac, Linux) and map it to `127.0.0.1`, your `localhost`. Now, when the server starts up, it *will* be able to resolve this host and grab the port.

I'm sorry I can't go into lot's of detail (I already forgot all the details!), but this is roughly it :)